# Pythonic and fast way to create an array of values `[1, .., n]` that contain none of `[i_1, ..., i_r]`

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

What is a fast and pythonic way to create a list from `[1, ..., n]` that contains none of the numbers `[i_1, ..., i_r]`. For example, running this function on `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[2,3]` should return `[1, 4]`.

I am currently using a for loop to test "if `i` is in `[1, ..., n]`, then exclude it from the output array, else include it".

Is there a better and more pythonic way?

Comment: how large is your exclusion list?

Comment: Posting your actual code would be nice.

Comment: Is exclusion list contiguous?

Comment: Since both your lists seams to be sorted, you only need to check for one number (next one in the exclusion list)

Answer (score 2):

As a pythonic way you can go with :

```
n = 5
l = [k for k in range(1,n) if not k in [2,3] ]
```

Not sure about speed though.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Use a more efficient data type

One simple way to accomplish this task efficiently is to convert the exclusion list into a Python set, which makes lookup quite a lot faster (at least, if the exclusion list is of significant size):

```py
def range_excluding(limit, exclude):
    exclude = set(exclude)
    return (i for i in range(1, limit) if i not in exclude)
```

Note that the above returns a generator, not a list; you can turn it into a list by either calling `list` explicitly (`list(range_excluding(n, [1, 7, 12]))`) or by unpacking the generator (`[*range_excluding(n, [1, 7, 12])]`). The advantage of using the generator, though, is that it avoids excessive memory use if the range is very large and the results don't need to be stored.

Another way to write this is to use `itertools.filterfalse` to create a baseline `excluding` function:

```py
from itertools import filterfalse
def excluding(iterable, container):
    return filterfalse(container.__contains__, iterable)
```

This version depends on the caller to create the range iterable and to use an efficient datatype for exclusion lookup (which could be a set, a frozenset, or a dictionary, among other possibilities). I think that's better interface design because it gives the caller more flexibility; they can use any range (or other iterable), rather than insisting on a range starting 1, and they don't incur the overhead of converting a lookup table (say, a dictionary) which is already adequate to the purpose. Of course, nothing stops you from defining a convenience function which uses `excluding`:

```
>>> print([*excluding(range(1, 20), {1, 7, 12})])
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

>>> def list_excluding(limit, exclusions):
...     return [*excluding(range(1, limit), frozenset(exclusions))]
... 
>>> list_excluding(20, [12, 1, 7])
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

#### 2. Alternative: sort the exclusions and generate a sequence of ranges

If you know that the list to be filtered will always be a range, you could piece together a possibly more efficient solution [Note 1] based on sorting the exclusions, resulting in a sequence of subranges and then using itertools' convenient `chain.from_iterable` to combine the sequence into a single iterable. (I also used a number of other handy itertools functions, including `pairwise` which was added in 3.10; [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)) [Note 2]:

```py
from itertools import chain, pairwise, starmap

def range_excluding(start, stop, exclusions=None):
    '''Returns a generator over range(start, stop) which excludes
       the values in exclusions.
       If only two arguments are provided, the first is the end of
       the range, and the second is the list of exclusions.
    '''
    if exclusions is None:
        start, stop, exclusions = 0, start, stop
    return chain.from_iterable(
               starmap(lambda lo, hi: range(lo + 1, hi),
                       pairwise(chain((start - 1,),
                                      sorted(exclusions),
                                      (stop,)))))
```

---

#### Notes

1. On the basis of some very rough microbenchmarks using Python v3.11, it seems like this solution is significantly faster than the first solution if the range is fairly large compared to the number of exclusions. For smaller ranges, the first solution wins out.
2. Although that function uses a lot of Python features, I'm not sure if there would be any consensus about it being "pythonic" :-)

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic *and* fast way to do it:

```py
l = [k for k in range(1,n+1) if k < i_1 or k > i_r]
```

Note that this is O(n), while @Adrien Mau's answer is O(n²).

Comment: Hm.. you are assuming that the `i_1, ...i_r` form a contiguous range for themselves. I don't think that this necessarily is true.

Answer (score 0):

A numpy approach.

Step by step

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange( 1, 5 )

exclude = np.arange( 2,4 )

mask = np.equal.outer( arr, exclude )
# mask  is a 2D array. true where arr (as rows) equals exclude ( as columns ). 

mask
# array([[False, False],
#        [ True, False],
#        [False,  True],
#        [False, False]])

~np.logical_or.reduce( mask, axis = 1)  # `not logical_or` across the columns
# array([ True, False, False,  True])

arr[ ~np.logical_or.reduce( mask, axis = 1) ]
# array([1, 4])
```

As a function

```
def do_exclude( arr, exclude ):
    mask = np.equal.outer( arr, exclude )
    return arr[ ~np.logical_or.reduce( mask, axis = 1) ]

do_exclude( arr, exclude )
# array([1, 4])

arr = np.arange( 20 )

exclude = np.array( [ 1, 7, 12 ] )

do_exclude( arr, exclude )
# array([ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```